# Angular - get title list from json placeholder

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have created a simple service with Angular version 4 where I return an array with a few titles:

Here's the code:

```
//post.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class PopstService {

  constructor() {}

  showPosts() {
    return ['title1', 'title2', 'title3'];
  }

}
```

Instead of having it hardcoded in the service page I'd like to gt the titles from some json data instead.

Here's the url:

https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

Data looks like this:

```
0   
userId  1
id  1
title   "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit"
body    "quia et suscipit\nsuscip… rem eveniet architecto"
1   
userId  1
id  2
title   "qui est esse"
body    "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
```

How can I modify this service to return the titles from the online json instead of my current hardcoded titles?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1. Create A service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import  'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ProductService{
  private _productUrl = 'api url';
  constructor (private _http:Http){}

  getProductsHttp():Observable<any> {
      return this._http.get(this._productUrl)
          .map((response: Response) => <any> response.json())
          .do(data => console.log('All: ' +  JSON.stringify(data)))
          .catch(this.handleError);
  }

  private handleError(error: Response) {
      console.error(error);
      return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
  }
```

**Step 2 Change the Component like below**

```
constructor(private _producrService:ProductService)  {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
      //this.products=this._producrService.getProducts();
      this._producrService.getProductsHttp()
              .subscribe(products => this.products = products,
                         error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);

  }
```